# Using Powershell against a DataReader's GetSchemaTable() method

Tags: powershell

I'm running a stored procedure and am trying to filter out which columns are returned by GetSchemaTable()

```
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
$schemaTable = $reader.GetSchemaTable();
foreach ($row in $schemaTable.Rows)
{
    foreach ($column in $schemaTable.Columns)
    {
        write-host $column;
    }
}
```

...shows me a whole bunch of column names I don't care about and 2 that i do:

ColumnName and ColumnOrdinal

How do I go about restricting output to just those to fields?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
$reader.GetSchemaTable() | Select ColumnName, ColumnOrdinal
```